# Can't stop eggs from sticking to stainless steel pan

Tags: frying, stainless-steel

I've made omelettes in this pan before without any problems, but fried eggs are impossible to make without sticking.I heat the pan, throw few drops of water and check if they move around (some would say like mercury), lower the heat, pour oil and then put eggs in.I've tried to monitor the temperature carefully to make sure that the pan isn't too hot, still no success.Is my pan the problem?

Comment: get a cast iron pan. they are cheap and excellent. the "seasoning" on the pan is a polymer that acts as non-stick but without many of the downsides of plastic non-stick coatings.

Comment: Do you not want to use a nonstick / teflon type pan?  Eggs are easy in my nonstick pan.

Comment: Using the pan I already have is easier and cheaper than finding another one.Besides, it seems as if we have no idea if non stick coatings are safe or not.

Answer (score 1):

If food sticks to a stainless steel pan it is usually due to either a) too high heat, b) not enough grease/butter/oil, or c) some amount of both a and b.

Comment: I don't think the heat is too high as I repeat the water test often.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using a spray on (canola oil), instead of liquid (canola oil).

Answer (score 0):

If you have indeed heated up your pan, then you're most likely not using enough oil.

Comment: I've used far more oil than usual this time.Results - eggs, like before, start browning around edges too soon (temperature can't be too high as I repeat the water test every ~30 seconds), while they didn't stick completely, taking them out wasn't easy and I barely removed the crusty brown part from the bottom.